# Sharepoint sync on ubuntu

Tags: synchronisation, onedrive-for-business, linux

Is it possible to have "Team sites" from sharepoint synced on an ubuntu machine? I am searching for a OneDrive for busnesses sync alternative to run on my ubuntu laptop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a an implementation of the the [Sharepoint 2013 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142380%28v=office.15%29.aspx) in Python in the [sharepoint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sharepoint/) python package.

Unfortunately [python-onedrive](https://github.com/mk-fg/python-onedrive) will not work, as it does not support the Onedrive for Business API.

I have not tested python-sharepoint yet, as I only found it by checking up on this answer. But it looks promising.

Comment: I can confirm that the python-onedrive doesn't support the onedrive for business API. Thx for the info though